# Can you use cookies for routing in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, url-routing

I'm running my SPA from a network drive in Internet Explorer (yes it has to be in IE 8+ unfortunately).  So the URL looks something like this...

```
\\server\netShareName\projectName\index.html
```

AngularRouting doesn't work...   at all!  You can't use hashes in Internet Explorer when loading from a network location like this.  I'm rackin' my brains looking for a way to get routing working without using the hash or search properties of the url.

I thought perhaps you could setup a $watch on a global variable that gets saved to a cookie in case the page reloads.  I think this could work but I don't know how to get it done.

Thanks for any grand ideas you can offer!

Comment: cookies are an http kinda thing, so use http if you want cookies.

Comment: Yah, but they work from here.  Just not sure how to implement with routing.  I'm not stuck on using Angular's cooking functions either.